# Difference between Rubies Directory and Gem Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

I'm trying to solve some issues with Passenger. I am currently using **ruby-1.9.3-p392**. When I cd into my application directory I get this message:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p429 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p429'
```

and I noticed that in my "rvm info" the ENV has a few instances of ruby mentioned:

```
environment:
PATH: "/usr/local/heroku/bin:
       /Users/jem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:
       /Users/jem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:
       /Users/jem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:
```

So viewing the directories I see:

```
  ➜  .rvm  cd rubies
  ➜  rubies  ll
     total 8
     drwxr-xr-x   8 jem   staff   272 May 22 10:41 ./
     drwxr-xr-x  30 jem   staff  1020 May 22 11:22 ../
     lrwxr-xr-x   1 jem   staff    38 May 22 10:41 default@ -> /Users/jem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Dec  7  2012 ree-1.8.7-2012.02/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.8.7-p358/
     drwxr-xr-x   9 jem   staff   306 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.9.2-p290/
     drwxr-xr-x   8 jem   staff   272 Dec  8  2012 ruby-1.9.3-p327/
     drwxr-xr-x   8 root  staff   272 Mar 13  2013 ruby-1.9.3-p392/
  ➜  rubies  ll ../gems
     total 0
     drwxr-xr-x  15 jem   staff   510 Jul 30 22:38 ./
     drwxr-xr-x  30 jem   staff  1020 May 22 11:22 ../
     drwxr-xr-x   2 jem   staff    68 Dec  7  2012 cache/
     drwxr-xr-x   3 jem   staff   102 Dec  7  2012 ree-1.8.7-2012.02/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Dec  7  2012 ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.8.7-p358/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.9.2-p290/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Mar 20  2013 ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/
     drwxr-xr-x   8 jem   staff   272 Mar 13  2013 ruby-1.9.3-p327/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Dec  7  2012 ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 Dec  7  2012 ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 jem   staff   238 May 21 23:48 ruby-1.9.3-p392/
     drwxr-xr-x   7 root  staff   238 Mar 13  2013 ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/
     drwxr-xr-x   2 jem   staff    68 Jul 30 22:38 ruby-1.9.3-p429/
```

So my question is, what are the differences of the two directories and could this redundancy cause me problems?  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rubies` are versions of Ruby / different Ruby interpreters installed on your machine.

`gems` are gem sets for each of those versions.  Each comes with a `global` which is used if you switch to a version of Ruby on your machine using RVM and *do* apply to all project specific gemsets.  However, you can also specify a set of gems unique to a particular project, like your `ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd` gemset.

[Here is the documentation](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) for RVM gemsets.

Comment: OK!  So I am good?  Can you tell why I am being asked to install **ruby-1.9.3-p429**

Comment: Is there a reference in the project to that specific version of Ruby?  Perhaps in an `.rvmrc` or `.ruby-version` file?  See: http://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't the gems in a `global` gemset available in all the gemsets of that particular Ruby, while the gems in e.g. `ree-1.8.7-2012.02/` are the ones that are usable (plus the ones in `ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/`) if you don't specify a gemset?

Comment: You are correct.  http://rvm.io/gemsets/global - Good catch, I've updated my answer.